# Webdriver does not support my chrome version

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have been working with selenium and its tools for a long time. As of today, Chrome has moved to version 116 and the support for webdrivers remains at version 114.

As a result, my systems are currently down, should I wait for the webdriver to support version 116? Is there any other solution? It may be inconvenient to downgrade my Chrome version.

Comment: AFAIK the 115 chromedriver still isn't fully released (see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) and it's been that way for some time. If you're going to wait for a full (non-testing) 116 chromedriver you might be waiting for some time. Have you considered using Firefox?

Comment: You can get a testing version for 116 here: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

Comment: Will it be enough to download the browser to my computer to use firefox

Comment: but these are browsers, not webdrivers @DarkKnight

Comment: chromedrivers are also available on that page including a 116 version - e.g., https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/116.0.5845.96/mac-x64/chromedriver-mac-x64.zip

Comment: thx i downloaded version 116 webdriver but i still cant use it with undetected_chromedriver. I added the "driver_executable_path" parameter to the Chrome class and added the path of the webdriver I just downloaded as path, but I got the same error. @DarkKnight

Comment: driver = Chrome(driver_executable_path=r'C:\Users\Kullanıcı\Desktop\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the selenium version which you are using is either `4.10.0` or lower. This version of selenium can support only up to `CDP version 114`.

**Solution:** Just upgrade your selenium to latest version which is `v4.11.2`, and selenium's browser and driver management tool which is `Selenium Manager` should be able to download the required drivers for `116` browser.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912466/7598774

Comment: thx but I use undetected chromedriver, how can i upgrade it?

Comment: `undetected chromedriver` is a different library all together. You need to upgrade your `selenium webdriver` to version `4.11.2`

Comment: I did it but now it says "WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'"

Comment: Yes that's expected. `executable_path` is deprecated in the latest selenium. Show me your code. Don't supply the driver path now. Selenium will download it for you.

Comment: already not using it, it started giving me irrelevant errors: driver = Chrome(options=options, service_args=['--verbose'])

Comment: Can you edit your question and update your code there?

Comment: I solved it. I also updated the undetected chromedriver and specified version 116 chromedriver as "driver_executable_path".

Comment: Thanks, but I looked at Java Maven and Nuget for C# last night and latest Selenium was 4.11.0

Comment: @K.hervey - For Java binding, latest stable selenium version is `v4.11.0`, for C# it is `4.11.0` and for Python it is `v4.11.2`. Hope this helps. https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

Comment: @Shawn  Thanks.  I just need to figure how to get Maven and especially Nuget to use the less stable 4.11.2.

Thanks again