# Troubleshooting Selenium Error After Upgrading to Chrome 116: Seeking Resolution

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm encountering an error while executing Python code with Selenium. The problem appears to be related to the version of Chrome I'm using. I've upgraded Chrome from version 114 to the latest stable version, 116. I've also updated the ChromeDriver to the most recent version. Despite these updates, the issue remains unresolved. I would greatly appreciate assistance in diagnosing and resolving this problem.

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.110 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
Stacktrace:
#0 0x561777b924e3 <unknown>
#1 0x5617778c1c76 <unknown>
#2 0x5617778ef04a <unknown>
#3 0x5617778ea4a1 <unknown>
#4 0x5617778e7029 <unknown>
#5 0x561777925ccc <unknown>
#6 0x56177792547f <unknown>
#7 0x56177791cde3 <unknown>
#8 0x5617778f22dd <unknown>
#9 0x5617778f334e <unknown>
#10 0x561777b523e4 <unknown>
#11 0x561777b563d7 <unknown>
#12 0x561777b60b20 <unknown>
#13 0x561777b57023 <unknown>
#14 0x561777b251aa <unknown>
#15 0x561777b7b6b8 <unknown>
#16 0x561777b7b847 <unknown>
#17 0x561777b8b243 <unknown>
#18 0x7f89faf3f609 start_thread
```

Comment: the version is not correct,  the browser version is too higher compared to ChromeDriver.

Comment: Yes. But I am not able to install the chrome 114 version. So could you please help me for this

Comment: You need to upgrade the selenium version. Refer these answers - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912466/7598774 https://stackoverflow.com/a/76921020/7598774

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114. LATEST\_RELEASE\_115 doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76913935/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-this-version-of-chromedri)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your requirement is to really test on Google Chrome 114, I would suggest to not downgrade it. You can update the chromedriver version to the one compatible with chrome 116.
Chromedriver 116 is available and can be downloaded from this [link](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable).

**NB**: The issue with version mismatch can be resolved using WebDriverManager (to handle driver and chrome version mismatch). A solution to this problem has been provided in this post. [post]: ([SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296873/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-created-this-version-of-chrome))

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't worked since new version is unavailable. This answer wont work for the latest release

Comment: Chromedriver 116 is already available : [see this](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable). Also this google support group post has a solution the issue you are facing https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/230521170?hl=en&msgid=231461691

Comment: webDriverManager doesn't work for me. But I resolved the issue by download chromedriver 116 from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76957928/troubleshooting-selenium-error-after-upgrading-to-chrome-116-seeking-resolution/76961570#comment135683159_76961808:~:text=is%20already%20available%20%3A-,see%20this,-.%20Also%20this%20google)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the chromedriver which has a version compatible with Chrome for testing 116. You can download it from https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable depending on your operating system (Linux, Windows, etc) and then you should set the executable path of your chromedriver correctly.

Also, I don't know which Selenium version you're using but do not run this `webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`, otherwise you are ignoring the previous chromedriver you downloaded from the link. Instead run `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver")` where `"/path/to/chromedriver"` is the path of your chromedriver, ideally located in the same directory of your Python script. If not, you should set the executable path properly.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Chrome version 116 doesn't require Chromedriver to be passed as an external resource. Now it is part of the selenium library.

Just upgrade the python library to selenium 4.11.2. and remove the chromedriver path. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

**I got it to work following these steps**

1. Uninstall your selenium 4 version and install selenium 3.14 by

```
pip install selenium==3.14
```

2. Install the `webdriver-manager` package the `webdriver-manager` package should be the latest version (4.0.0)
3. Add the following two lines at the top of your Python file

```
import os
os.environ['WDM_SSL_VERIFY']='0'
```

4. Initialize your driver as

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

5. Run the script it should work