# Selenium Driver issue - Getting the Chrome browser Version failure

Tags: unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

I'm unable to run the selenium script when using below code snippet

Note: I'm using Selenium version 4

Please find the attached code snippet below
[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1am8.png)

Please find the error message snap below
[Error stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2SCk.png)

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
```

Please find the current browser version
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade chromedriver to version 116. This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76961808/11916657)

In these kind of situations , I use WebDriverManager to handle driver and chrome compatibility issues. See https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick fix:** Just upgrade your selenium version from `v4.10.0` to `v4.11.0`

**Issue:** Since you are using chrome version `116`, the compatible selenium web driver version is the latest one which is `v4.11.0`

If you use Maven, update your POM.xml as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912466/7598774