# How can we download chromedriver 117?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

My Chrome browser got updated to version 117, and now I need to download chromedriver 117 for running automation scripts. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I think  the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76957928/troubleshooting-selenium-error-after-upgrading-to-chrome-116-seeking-resolution

Answer (score 11):

If we are using Chrome version 115 or newer, we need to check [Chrome for Testing availability dashboard](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable). This page provides convenient JSON endpoints for specific ChromeDriver version downloading.

Below is the link where you will be able to download latest `chromedriver` from, in your case `version 117`

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

**Suggesstion:** Having said the above, if you use latest selenium version `v4.12.0` or higher, you do not have to worry about downloading the `chromedriver` manually, selenium's new in-built tool [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) will download and manage the drivers for you automatically.

Code to launch browser can be as simple as:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Few references:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
- https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/

Answer (score 5):

For Python, assuming you're using selenium `4.11.2` (or newer), selenium automatically gets the correct driver for you as needed:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

You can also use the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) driver manager: (`pip install seleniumbase`)

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome")
driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to link: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Click on "the Chrome for Testing availability dashboard": which is the URL.
It will take you to link: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

Here, click on "Stable" (it’s a URL again).

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVPvD.png)

Copy and paste the link in browser. It will download chromedriver in .zip format.

Comment: This solves my dilemma with a 2018 course I am taking from Udemy.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
pip install --upgrade selenium

python -m pip install --upgrade selenium
```

This will resolve all the problems.

Comment: Why would you run both of these commands?