# Selenium webdriver not working for chrome 117

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use the Python Chrome web driver using Selenium. This is the code I am running. It was working fine but stopped working after updating the chrome to 117

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

service = Service()

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

This is the error message

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 117.0.5938.149 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

selenium version

```
"version": "==4.13.0"
```

I have tried deleting the chrome driver binary from the path mentioned but It is still picking the 114 binary

Comment: Let Selenium Manager download the latest `chromedriver` automatically for you. Do not pass the `chromedriver.exe` manually. Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: Check this answer too - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77111183/7598774

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the **Service()** class along with **ChromeDriverManager().install()**

- The [webdriver_manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) library, such as ChromeDriverManager provides a convenient way to install and manage browser drivers. It downloads the appropriate driver executable for the specified browser version and operating system.
- The advantage of using webdriver_manager is that it can automatically check the latest version of the browser driver and download the corresponding version if needed. This ensures that your code works with the latest browser and driver versions without requiring manual intervention.
- Using webdriver_manager in your code simplifies the process of managing browser drivers and ensures compatibility between your code and the browser being used.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
browser.get("Url")
```