# Why selenium not started

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I downloaded selenium (`114.0.5735.90` the latest version on the site)
I'm trying to run, I have chrome updated to version 118, literally just now
Here's what

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException writes in the raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) log
: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 118.0.5993.71 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

I'm working with selenium for the first time, what to do, why such a mistake

I don't know what to do yet

Comment: Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have downloaded the `chromedriver.exe` from following link - https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

For chrome version `115` or newer, you need to download the `chromedriver.exe` from following path - https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

Having said the above, you really do not have to worry about manually downloading the driver binaries, [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) will do the driver management for you.

Python code to launch browser can be as simple as:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

And Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");  
}
```

Few useful answers on this subject:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/77111183/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774