# Getting a mismatch with the chrome version for selenium project

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

My code was working earlier but when I used gradle command line to run the project, I got this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha3Xk.png)
I'm using bonigarcia library so the incompatibility issue with the chrome version on my system should not arise.

Tried changing the selenium library and webdrivermanager library but then it renders the whole project unusable.

Gradle File:

```
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'
    testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:7.4.0'
    implementation group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '5.4.1'
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.22'
    implementation group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-testng', version: '2.17.1'

}

test {
    useTestNG()
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'
```

You are using way too old selenium. Upgrade to the latest version of selenium i.e. `v4.15.0`.

And once you upgrade to latest selenium, you no longer need `WebDriverManager` library. The new built-in tool [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/) will do what `WebDriverManager` used to do before.

Code can be as simple as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    driver.quit();
}
```

Refer below answers for more details on this topic:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76752843/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912466/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/77281456/7598774

Comment: I upgraded the selenium version but I was trying with webdrivermanager.
So you're saying I don't need to do chromedriver setup? Do I need to save chromedriver file like earlier selenium versions?

Comment: Thanks, this worked.