Unable to navigate to any URL in Microsoft Edge using Selenium in Windows 11
I'm getting this error:

selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist.

Code:
public class TestSample{
 public static void main(String args[]){
   WebDriver driver;
   WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup(); //also tried with System.setProperty option
   driver = new EdgeDriver();
   driver.get("http://www.google.com");
   }
}

Same code is working fine in Windows 10.
Dependencies used:
Selenium-java: 4.25.0
webdrivermanager: 5.9.2
Edge version: 130.0.2849.26

webdrivermanager is part of Selenium-java (since version 4.6 I think). Do not add explicit dependency on it. And remove your line WebDriverManager....

@SiKing - "webdrivermanager is part of Selenium-java (since version 4.6 I think)" - Am sure you meant SeleniumManager not WDM.

Some additional information here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50642308/3124333

You don't really need WebDriverManager or System.setProperty any more to manage browser drivers(Unless there is a specific need to do so).
You can simply use Selenium Manager to handle and manage the browsers. Best part is, this feature is built-in into the selenium package. So no need of extra libraries or extra lines of code.
Try this:
WebDriver driver;
driver = new EdgeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

Few references:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77574327/7598774
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78365546/7598774


Tried it as well. Same response, its opening the browser but not navigating to google page.
