# ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 not 160

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

I've got the following error when my Chrome browser got updated to version 160:

```
"org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 119.0.6045.160 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'"
```

My POM file settings:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried to bump up webdrivermanager to 5.6.2 but it did not help.
Anyone can help with this issue?
Thanks a lot!!!

I tried to bump up webdrivermanager version and it did not help

Comment: There is no "Chrome 160"... the highest version in preview is 120.

Answer (score 0):

```
<version>3.141.59</version>
```

You are using very old version of Selenium. Upgrade to the latest version of selenium i.e. `v4.15.0`.

And once you upgrade to latest selenium, you no longer need `WebDriverManager` library. The new built-in tool `Selenium Manager` will do what `WebDriverManager` used to do before.

Code can be as simple as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    driver.quit();
}
```

Refer below answers for more details on this topic:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76752843/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/77281456/7598774

Comment: WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); raises exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/HasDownloads

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.HasDownloads
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)