# Getting below error while running selenium code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 122
Current browser version is 121.0.6167.161 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe 
Build info: version: '4.18.1', revision: 'b1d3319b48'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:519)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:233)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:52)
    at SeleniumIntro.main(SeleniumIntro.java:17)
```

Below is my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;

public class SeleniumIntro {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
        
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://google.com");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the below line from your code, you don't need it. Let [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) do the driver management.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
```

To know more about Selenium Manager, check the below answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/77281456/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774