# Which version of Chrome Driver should I download for selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

Now, I am using Chrome browser Version 119.0.6045.160. But the latest Chrome Driver version, I downloaded is "ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90"

For this code in python,

```
from selenium import webdriver

import os

os.environ['PATH'] += r"D:/chromedriver_win32"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

[I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn5Pr.png)

How, to fix this error?

Comment: did you install `webdriver-manager`?

Comment: I just installed chromedriver from this url to watch a youtube video
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: For those of you who do not want to use third party library line `webdriver-manager`, check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77111183/7598774

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `selenium version >4.11.0`

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bing.com/")
```

Or

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/
https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/
https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/status_of_selenium_manager_in_october_2023/

Answer (score 2):

First you need to install `webdriver-manager`

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

For selenium 4 here is the demo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(
    ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("http://www.python.org")

driver.close()
```

If you are using selenium 3 then:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("http://www.python.org")

driver.close()
```