# AutoSelectCertificateForUrls for "Chrome for Testing"

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, chrome-for-testing

This is my first time to have a post here; however, I have learnt so much valuable knowledge from the forum. Hope to have some advice from experts for my below issue.

My Python program is set up to access an internal website through Google Chrome requiring selection of valid certificate to perform some actions. I have used Selenium and Google Group policies: `AutoSelectCertificateForUrls` to automatically select required certificate without any problems so far.

However, given recent changes of Google Chrome, I have to manually download a new chrome driver for Google Chrome whenever it updates to a newer version. I tried many ways to disable Google Chrome update but it keeps updating.

I see "Chrome for Testing" could be a solution because it will not be automatically updated.

However, using "Chrome for Testing" requires my program to manually select valid certificate even though `AutoSelectCertificateForUrls` was set up for Google Chrome.

I think I need to set up Google Group policies: AutoSelectCertificateForUrls separately for "Chrome for Testing"; but still can't find a way.

Please help.

Thanks

I tried to create a new registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome for Testing\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls along with HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls
```

but it only works for Google Chrome, not for Chrome for Testing browser.
I also tried to move the folder `chrome-win64` containing Chrome for Testing application to the same position with the original Google Chrome but still failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***However, given recent changes of Google Chrome, I have to manually download a new chrome driver for Google Chrome whenever it updates to a newer version***

Regarding your statement above, you don't really have to manually download each time the Google Chrome gets updated. If you are using the latest selenium, the new built-in tool [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/), will do the driver management for you. Whenever there is an update to Google Chrome, selenium will automatically download the matching `chromedriver.exe` from web and use it in your code.

Refer below answers for more info:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76574264/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/77111183/7598774

Comment: Thanks Shawn! 
I actually used WebDriverManager for a long time before, and then got trouble when Chrome issued Chrome for Testing as it failed to download correct webdriver. I also knew in-built Selenium Manager thanks to your answer on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774.
However, to avoid the similar issue happening with Selenium Manager in the future, I prefer finding the more stable way: not allow Chrome to be updated by using Chrome for Testing.