# regarding chrome driver extension file

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I see my chrome is updated with the version 119.0.6045.160 (Official Build) (64-bit) and I need a extensions for this anyone could help me in this I tied to find this latest version of .exe here https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads but could not fond it

I need exe file for this version 119.0.6045.160

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from chrome version `115`, Google Chrome team have changed the URL from where you can download the required `chromedriver.exe`.

Visit the below URL and download the required `chromedriver.exe` as per your platform(i.e. Linux, mac, windows-32 or windows-64)

URL - https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

Refer this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77111183/7598774

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same issue.**

As @Shawn said, URL has changed for Google Chrome version `115 and later.`
This is the link to download newer version of Chrome and corresponding chromedriver
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

Despite this, everything was going smooth for the past few months since this has changed, but today my auto-updating script failed at finding the chromedriver corresponding to my **stable** version of Chrome `(119.0.6045.160)`.

Earliest stable version of chromedriver availiable is `119.0.6045.105` and upcoming stable release is `119.0.6045.159`

***The solution that worked for me:*** Use the portable version of chrome and corresponding chromedriver that can be downloaded on https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

then run selenium and indicate the location of each binaries.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = './chrome-linux64/chrome'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver', options=options)
```

if you want to automatically download last version of chrome for testing, you can query https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE then find corresponding download links in https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json