# Getting org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException with chrome version 120

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting the below exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 120.0.6099.217 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Tried below solutions:

> 1. Updated the s4lj dependency
> 2. bonigarcia: Tried different maven versions
> 3. Updated the chromedriver.exe file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception which you are getting is telling you that, the `chromedriver.exe` which you are using in your code works with Chrome version `114`. However, the Chrome version installed in your system is `v120`.

**Solution:** You need to download the latest `chromedriver.exe` from the new [Chrome for testing Dashboard](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/). And then use that `.exe` file to set your driver path.

Use below link to download `chromedriver.exe` for Chrome version `120`

[Link to download latest stable chrome driver](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable)

As an alternate solution, you can utilise latest selenium's tool which is known as [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/). Using this, you no longer need to download and set the chrome driver path manually. Selenium will internally handle the browser driver for you. For more info, refer below answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/77111183/7598774

Comment: It is working now. Thanks a lot, Shawn.

Comment: Hi Shawn, 
I'm using  WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); to get the browser driver automatically but I'm still getting this issue.
It is working fine if we download the chromedriver file manually. Is there any other solution?

Comment: You don't need WebDriverManager anymore, selenium has an in-built tool known as SeleniumManager which can do the chrome driver management.

Comment: If you still want to use `WebDriverManager`, try to use latest version `5.6.3`. The latest version may download driver automatically.