# How to fix: Could not start a new session.Response code 500.Message: session not created:This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

OS : Windows server

Language : Java

Chrome version : 120.0.6099.130

Chrome driver version : 114.0.5735.90

OUTPUT :

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 120.0.6099.130 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe 
Host info: host: 'CATPOWER', ip: '***'
Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: []}}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:96)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:232)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at mangia.ro.Autentificare.setup(Autentificare.java:18)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:361)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:296)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:644)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:633)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:595)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:431)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:391)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Please, help me with this. I tried to update the chrome driver version too, but without success. I followed the first steps, but I couldn't understand well the last one.

Comment: *"I tried to update the chrome driver"* - That's exactly what you would do to address this error.  *"I followed the first steps, but I couldn't understand well the last one."* - We don't know what you mean by that or what problem you encountered.  Please clarify.

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77800092/7598774

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public class Register {

    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup(Method method) {

        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        driver.get("https://suriyaparithy.blogspot.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(60));

    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).