# Cannot find Chrome binary with Selenium Webdriver using Eclipse IDE, Maven and JUnit

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, junit

I'm starting to learn Selenium Webdriver with Maven project with Eclipse IDE and Junit. Once I ran the test it says that couldn't start the session and find the Chrome Binary and other one saying

> Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 15076
> Only local connections are allowed.
> Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
> ChromeDriver was started successfully.

:

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

**My file called GoogleSearchTest.java**

```
package com.qualitystream.tutorial;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class GoogleSearchTest {
    
    private WebDriver driver;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./src/test/resources/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Test
    public void testGooglePage() {
        
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        searchBox.clear();
        searchBox.sendKeys("quality-stream Introducción a la Automatización de Pruebas de Software");
        searchBox.submit();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        assertEquals("quality-stream Introducción a la Automatización de Pruebas de Software - Google Search",driver.getTitle());
    }
    
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        //driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**Project Structure:**

[image: Project structure]

**POM.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.qualitystream.tutorial</groupId>
  <artifactId>QualityStreamTutorial</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <dependencies>
      
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.17.0</version>
        </dependency>

      
      <dependency>
       <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
       <artifactId>accessors-smart</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.0</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.13-beta-1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
  
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I expecting to ran the automation using Google Chrome and JUnit

Comment: Do you have a chrome browser installed in your system?

Comment: Yes I have! now i got this error: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 121.0.6167.140 with binary path C:\ I'm will look for solutions

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77800092/7598774

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76843959/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-could-not-start-a-new-session-r)