# SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, version, http-status-code-500, undetected-chromedriver

I Need to solve this issue. I'm facing this issue from past 3 days.

```
Aug 23, 2023 9:51:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default; https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#setting-log-output
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.97 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-2CR94PT', ip: '192.168.176.203'
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '20.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: []}}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:96)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:531)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:227)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:154)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:87)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:50)
    at test.Seleniumscript.main(Seleniumscript.java:14)
```

Comment: Chromedriver is picky about versions.  Basically the major version must match the browser version.  Right now your Chromedriver is v114 and the browser is at v116.  Update Chromedriver to v116 to fix or disable buildcheck in chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick fix:** Just upgrade your selenium version from `v4.10.0` to `v4.11.0`

**Issue:** Since you are using chrome version `116`, the compatible selenium web driver version is the latest one which is `v4.11.0`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912466/7598774