# Serenity BDD Unable to download Updated version of chromeDriver, after Chrome version update 116

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-java, serenity-bdd

Exception:

```
Caused by: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver (Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.180 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Comment: You need to upgrade your selenium version. Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912466/7598774